# Clearing sharedpreferences everday at 12am

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-asynctask, sharedpreferences

I want to clear the shared preferences (with a method i already have) everyday or at 12am everyday. But if i use an alarm which extends broadcast receiver. I am not able to access the method or cant use the `editor.clear();` method of shared preferences

Method Code:

```
public void clearSharedPreference() {
    SharedPreferences settings;
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor;

    settings = this.getSharedPreferences(PREF, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    editor = settings.edit();

    editor.clear();
    editor.commit();
}
```

Comment: post code and error log

Comment: @HRaval posted it

Comment: what is PREF...have you assign it

Comment: debug it and test it for less time

Comment: PREF is defined and the method is working. I just want to call it at 12am or at 00:00(24hrs format)

Comment: Add in service and use alaram manager.